# Why is the select statement not selecting all the rows from the database table? It is ignoring the first entry every time

Tags: python, html, sql, forms

I am trying to get the names from a database table into a dropdown but the SELECT statement is ignoring the first row.

I am doing it using python.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM ArtistDetails"
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print(f"<option>{x[1]}</option>")
print("""
</select>
<br>
""")
```

Sample data

[image: Sample data]

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] by including sample data for which it fails

Comment: Side note: without an `order by` clause, the notion of *first* record does not really make sense...

Comment: but where is open <select> ?

Answer (score 0):

ok , here an example

```
sql = "SELECT Artist_Id,ArtistName FROM ArtistDetails"
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
tag = '<select>'
for row in myresult:
        print row["Artist_Id"], row["ArtistName"]
        tag=tag+f"<option value='{row["Artist_Id"]}'>{row["ArtistName"]}</option>"

tag=tag+'</select>'
print(tag)
```